# Single instance of non modal form in non mdi application

Tags: vb.net

I need one form to be single instance one.
This is kind of "tool form" and I cannot start it with NEW because then it forgot user inputs.
However, in that form I have Sub New where I initialize some needed stuff.

If I call this form from main form like this:

```
With frm_iemail()
    .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    .FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    .Show(Me)
End With
```

I get error:

> 'frm_iemail' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

But if I call it like this:

```
Dim eform As New frm_iemail()
With eform
etc...
```

Then there is not error but entered text in textboxes are erased what is unwanted.

What to do here to get desired functionality?

Comment: So the form is already open and you want to reactivate it. right?

Comment: Yes, that I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an already active form then you can use the following method to get an object of active form.

```
Private Function GetActiveEmailForm() As frm_iemail

    For Each lForm In System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms
        If (lForm.Name = frm_iemail.Name) Then
            Return lForm
        End If
    Next

    Return New frm_iemail

End Function
```

And the main code would go like this.

```
Dim eform As frm_iemail = GetActiveEmailForm
With eform
etc...
```

Comment: Error 1 'OpenForms' is not a member of 'xcommon.My.MyApplication'. xcommon is not a tipical application but dll, can this be a problem?

Comment: So, this form is part of your application or another dll? Also let me know the status of the form when you are trying to access it.

Comment: This form is part of dll but should be accessible from whole solution. Form from which I call is also in same project, same dll. What is status of the form?

Comment: Why do you have to use xcommon.My.MyApplication? can't you simply use My.MyApplication.OpenForms?

Comment: I do use like you posted, but this is exact error message I get. xcommon is a project which contain those forms.

Comment: How do you enter text to the form for the first time? Is it added programatically? "entered text in textboxes are erased" you must be showing the form at least once to get the values in textbox.

Comment: No, for first time they are empty. Then I enter some text, exit form by hide it and then I would like to open it that there would be entered text. But problem is somewhere before that since on line "With frm_iemail" frm_email is underlined blue. If I remove Sub New from frm_iemail then things work like you described.

Comment: Check the updated code. Use System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.

Answer (score 0):

(I think) Your problem is this line:

```
With frm_iemail()
```

you are trying to use a form array in a With statement which wont work. Remove the brackets at the end and it should work.

In VB you can just reference the name of the form (you don't have to declare a form variable to use it)

So say I have a form name `frmTest`

I can simply do this:

```
With frmTest
    .FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    .Show
End With
```

Comment: After removing brackets it is blue underlined again with same error message.

Comment: change frm_iemail to the actual name of the form - that should work

Comment: But frm_iemail IS actual name of my form for send an e-mail (name under properties). Or here is some "more actual" name?

Comment: Try to make sub New in your frmTest and put some code in it and try then.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Private eform As New frm_iemail()` to the calling class or form (you called it your "main form "), not in a method but as instance data.  That way it only gets created once.  Something like this:

```
Class MainForm : Form

   Private eform As New frm_iemail()


   Public Sub ExampleMethod()

      With eform
         .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
         .FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
         .Show(Me)
      End With

   End Sub

End Class
```